# Get Month, Day, Year, Day of week from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsstring, nsdate

How can I get the month, day, year, day of week, time, into separate values ​​from a NSString like this "2013-09-27 15:05:00"?

For example 2013-09-27 15:05:00
NSString month: September
NSString year: 2013
NSString day: 27
NSString weekday: Monday
NSString time: 15:05:00

Please help me!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a `NSDate` from your `NSString`, then you can separate the values with `NSDateComponents`

This should do it:

```
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: @"2013-09-27 15:05:00"];

unsigned int unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *breakdownInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:myDate];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do it using NSDateComponents as @Mikael said, or the other way is:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: @"2013-09-27 15:05:00"];

[df setDateFormat:@"dd"];

myDayString = [df stringFromDate:myDate];

[df setDateFormat:@"MMM"];

myMonthString = [df stringFromDate:myDate];

[df setDateFormat:@"yy"];

myYearString = [df stringFromDate:myDate];

[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

myTimeString = [df stringFromDate:myDate];

[df release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dateFromString: method of NSDateFormatter class. You will get NSDate object back. Once you have it, you can do further with it whatever you want. This is basically a date and time parser with bunch of options for every situation. Writing your own parser would be a bad idea...

Read completely [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i) in Apple Developer Documentation. Date and time are not trivial things, it is wise to be well informed how you can hand this information in different situations, especially when writing international apps.

Answer (score 0):

Untested code but it should work..please try

```
NSCalendar *myCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2013-09-27 15:05:00"];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:myDate];

NSString *day = [NSString stringWithFormat=@"%d", [dateComponents day]];
NSString *month = [NSString stringWithFormat=@"%d", [dateComponents month]];
NSString *year = [NSString stringWithFormat=@"%d", [dateComponents year]];
```